# Why does ContiguousArrayStorage<String> leak?

Tags: swift, memory-leaks

Steps to reproduce:

Create a new Xcode project: File -> New Project

Add a property: `let tags = ["1", "2"]` to AppDelegate

Go to Product -> Profile

Instruments show _ContiguousArrayStorage leak?

If you change `let tags = ["1", "2"]` to `let tags = "1"` the leak disappears.

Can someone explain why [String] leaks but String doesn't?

[image]

Xcode 8.0 (8A218a)

Comment: I have ContiguousArrayStorage<LayoutConstriant> leak...I think it is a bug?

Comment: I have this leak also with Swift 3 in Xcode 8... We can't even initialize a string array without it leaking? Seems like a simple thing that shouldnt be happening..